# Trying to speed up recursive function, but memozation is making it take longer

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I am trying to implement regulation 9.3 from the [FIDE Chess Olympiad pairing system](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/OlympiadPairingRules2022).

Below is the script I'm trying to run. When I comment out the `@cached` line, it actually runs faster. I want to use this function for even values of n up to ~100.

```py
import itertools
from copy import deepcopy
from memoization import cached

@cached
def pairing(n, usedTeams = [], teams = None, reverse = False):
    """
    Returns the pairings of a list of teams based on their index in their position in the pool.
    Arguments:
        n = number of Teams
        usedTeams = a parameter used in recursion to carry the found matches to the end of the recursion (i.e. a leaf node)
        teams = used in recursion ^^
        reverse = if you need to prioritize finding a pairing for the lowest rated team
    Returns:
        A list of lists of match pairings
    """

    # print('trying to pair', n, ' teams')
    # if n > 10:
    #     return None

    if teams is None:
        teams = list(range(0,n))
        global matches
        matches = []
    
    if reverse == True:
        teams.reverse()


    usedTeams = deepcopy(usedTeams)

    oppTeams = []

    if len(teams) == 2:
        usedTeams.append([teams[0], teams[1]])
        matches.append(usedTeams)

    elif len(teams) > 2:
            team = teams[0]
            oppTeams = [teams[i] for i in itertools.chain(range(round(n/2), n), range(round(n/2)-1,0,-1))]

            currUsed = deepcopy(usedTeams)
            for opp in oppTeams:

                newUsed = currUsed + [[team, opp]]

                if len(oppTeams) > 1:
                    tmpTeams = [t for t in teams if t not in [team, opp]]
                    pairing(len(tmpTeams), newUsed, tmpTeams)
    return matches

    
import time
start = time.process_time()

pairing(12, [], None)

print(time.process_time() - start)
```

Any tips for making this run faster, or using memoization differently?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `memoization` over the built-in `cache` from `functools`?

Comment: @Kraigolas because my arguments have unhashable data types, and this package allows for that.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to find out:

```
import itertools
from copy import deepcopy
from memoization import cached

# set up a records of call parameters
from collections import defaultdict
calls = defaultdict(int)


@cached
def pairing(n, usedTeams=[], teams=None, reverse=False):
    # count this call
    calls[(
        n, 
        tuple(tuple(t) for t in usedTeams) if usedTeams is not None else None, 
        tuple(teams) if teams is not None else None, 
        reverse
    )] += 1

    ...  # your same code here, left out for brevity


import time

start = time.process_time()

pairing(12, [], None)

print(time.process_time() - start)

# print the average number of calls for any parameter combination
print(sum(calls.values()) / len(calls))
```

Output:

```
0.265625
1.0
```

The average number of calls using *any* combination of parameters is 1.0 - in other words, memoization will do exactly nothing, except add overhead. Memoization can only speed up your code if the function gets called with the same parameters repeatedly, and only when that's sufficiently frequent to offset the overhead cost of memoization.

In this case, you're adding the overhead, but since the function is never called with the same parameters, not even once, there is no benefit.

And my test is being generous, assuming that `@cached` will somehow cleverly figure out that two lists passed in have the same contents for example, without incurring an impossible overhead - which I don't know it does. So, the test assumes the most favourable effectiveness of `@cached`, but to no avail.

More in general, it's safe to assume there's no magic sauce you can just throw at a program without some analysis and careful application to make it faster. If there were, the language / compiler would likely do it as a default, or offer it as an easy option (for example when trading space for speed, as with memoization). You can of course get lucky and have the particular sauce you throw at it work in some case, but even then it would probably pay to carefully analyse where it does the most good, or any good at all, instead of drowning your code in it.